Eigenvalues of an off-diagonal block symmetric matrix
Consider the the following symmetric off-diagonal block matrix:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & B \\ B' & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
where $B$ is rectangular. How are the eigenvalues of $A$ related to the eigenvalues of $BB'$?
For the case where $B$ is square, there is a solution here, namely the eigenvalues of $A$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $B'B$.
How can I deal with the case where $B$ is rectangular?

By the square matrix  $$A^2 = ((BB',0),(0,B'B) $$ is a diagonal block matrix of square matrices.

You use the Schur complement for block matrices. Suppose $B$ is $n\times m$ and wlog $n \geq m$, then $$\det(\lambda I -M)= \lambda^n \det(\lambda I - \lambda^{-1}B’B)  = \lambda^{n-m}\det(\lambda^2 I - B’B).$$
If $B$ is rectangular it’s not that different, you get the square roots of the eigenvalues of $B’B$ and then some zero eigenvalues to make up for the missing ranks.

[+1] A detail : adjective "some" isn't adequate because $n-m$ can be equal to an arbitrarily large value...

Thank you. How do you deal with the case $\lambda=0$?

Im not sure I understand what you mean by “deal with”. We have that $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity at least n-m.
